# Usage of the idiom “it never rains but it pours”

Tags: idioms

Is it possible to use the idiom
**it never rains but it pours** in the context of the following sentence. Or is there any idiom better suited for this sentence.

> not only had the accident cost his son's life, but his counsel fails to conduct his case properly in court. He ends up receiving no remedy. **It never rains but it pours**.

Comment: The rest of the quote has several problems, but the use of the idiom fits in this context, except it never rain**s**.

Comment: The idiom is 'It never rain**s** but it pours'.

Comment: Maybe just me, but it sounds _quite_ informal to use for such a serious set of circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not so sure that it is the right idiom for this situation. "[It never rains but it pours](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it+never+rains+but+it+pours)" is used to imply that a number of bad (or sometimes good) things happen one after the other in fairly quick succession. A similar British English expression is "[it's one thing after another](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It%27s+one+thing+after+another!)". I would imagine that some time would pass between a fatal accident and the subsequent court case - there would have been an inquiry into it for a start. Is that really a quick succession of bad events?

I would think a better idiom would be "[to add insult to injury](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Add+Insult+to+Injury)", which means to make a bad situation worse. For example:

> Not only had the accident cost his son's life, but, to add insult to injury, his counsel failed to conduct his case properly in court.